# Winterbash or Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, terminology, capitalization

*From the creators of The Space In Stack Overflow, and its sequel The Space In Stack Exchange, comes an all-new production…*

Yeah, should I put a space in "Winterbash"? Or are they interchangeable? <s>The tag name seems to suggest no space</s> well it looks like *someone* changed all the tags to add a space, but I've seen it used both ways.

As an additional question, should it be capitalized?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official name of the event has always been Winter Bash, with a space, and that's how it's been typed in all of our blog announcements.

But... that's not necessarily how it's always typed in casual conversation or on Meta, and Winterbash is also a fairly common substitution. Even I use both interchangeably *all the time*.

That said, Winter Bash is the name of an event, and is thus a proper noun, so it generally should be capitalized if you are keen on following proper grammar.

Comment: So... the tags are wrong, then ;)

Comment: Oooh... sneaky.

Comment: What? I didn't do anything... I've no idea what you're talking about! ;P