# "Winter Bash 2022" or "Winter Summer Bash 2022"?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2022

The *countdown* for this year's [Winter Bash (2022)](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) is started.

This time on the countdown page, the image is displayed as "Winter Summer Bash 2022". 
So shall we call it "Winter Bash 2022" or "Winter Summer Bash 2022"? 
Also instead of the tag [winter-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2022), shall we use [winter-summer-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-summer-bash-2022)?

Screenshot from the countdown page:

[image: Winter Summer Bash]

Comment: When talking about it, we should call it Winter Summer Bash 2022. Once people are familiar with the change, it'd likely be OK to refer to it with a shorter nickname like W/S Bash (like how folks shorten Stack Overflow to just SO).

Comment: It's... complicated, considering the page title explicitly says Winterbash 2022, and while [last year's Winter (Summer?) Bash](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021) also mentioned Summer, it's officially called [Winter Bash 2021](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/22/winter-bash-2021). (Also, which is correct, with or without a space?)

Comment: @Meta SE is infamous for making simple things complicated, sadly.

Comment: Maybe they should just call it a fancy hat festival. @MetaAndrewT. I either forgot or didn't notice that they included Summer last year; I thought this was a new thing.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT.: Per the answer to [Winterbash or Winter Bash?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303383/335251), it should indeed have a space.

Comment: Whatever you do, you may irritate somebody, if only by using a title that is vague or empty. Calling it end-of-year bash might irritate people on different calendars. Calling it seasonal bash will irritate others; we are always in some season or other.

Answer (score 7):

> Also instead of the tag [winter-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2022), shall we use [winter-summer-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-summer-bash-2022)?

There isn't any need for one *or* the other. Make one a synonym of the other.

I suggest [winter-summer-bash-2022](/questions/tagged/winter-summer-bash-2022) be the main one if that is the name of the event. It is also more inclusive to people in the Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: But people having spring or autumn will be offended now. Should be Winter Summer Spring Autumn Bash.

Comment: @Shadow I just returned from Tanzania. They don't have those seasons, just dry and rainy ones. I propose to have an [end-of-the-Gregorian-year-bash-2022], to make clear we also respect people who use different calendars.

Comment: @Glorfindel but some people don't follow that calendar and will get confused/offended that SE didn't chose their calendar.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Isn't the name Bash offensive for non Unix users? :)

Comment: Damn @dem that made me laugh hard. :-DDD

Comment: the-event-where-unicorns-wear-hats

Answer (score 7):

Since it is an annual event around the globe, why not call it *Annual Bash*, *Stack Bash*, or simply *Bash*, and forsake the seasonal label altogether?

[image]

Comment: At that point, might as well not give it a name . Jokes aside, none of these aren't very good for search engines, since bash is a well-known shell.