# Is there a way to turn Festive Hats on?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I remember, in days of old, we used to have hats appearing on our avatars at this time of year.

Is there a way to turn that on?

Or, have hats been denied to all for some reason.

I'm wearing a Christmas jumper today and thinking of building community spirit and good cheer.

Comment: *It has begun...*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The annual Winter Bash for this year will start on the 14<sup>th</sup> of December 2022, in 21:00 UTC time. It is the event which features various hats that can be placed over one's avatar.

There is a countdown timer over at https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The linked site begs the question what a "Winter Summer" is.

Comment: @Joachim ["Winter Bash 2022" or "Winter Summer Bash 2022"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384281)