# This year "Winter Bash" event page window title to be updated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, window-title, winter-bash-2022

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303384/312043), the Winter Bash event is called "Winter Bash", with a space.

In plain text:

> The official name of the event has always been Winter Bash, with a space, and that's how it's been typed in all of our blog announcements.

In previous years Winter Bash events page window title is also referred to as "Winter Bash". But this year Winter Bash [countdown page](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/)'s window title is displayed as "Winterbash 2022".

For consistency, can we have this year's event page window title also displayed as "Winter Bash" instead of Winterbash?

Screenshot of past few year's page title:

> [image: Winter Bash]

Web archive for the past few year's event pages:

| Year | Web Archive Link |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | http://web.archive.org/web/20211223075528/http://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/ |
| 2020 | http://web.archive.org/web/20201220125314/https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/ |
| 2019 | http://web.archive.org/web/20191212013228/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/ |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the `<title>` tag in an HTML page does not charge us per word like a newspaper would. Fixed!

Comment: [Binter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binter) Wash.